# Removing XML document element using SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I have have the following code:

```xml
<nutrition>
    <code>
        <lol1>energy</lol1>
        <lol2>protein</lol2>
        <lol3>fat</lol3>
    </code>
</nutrition>
```

and I want:

```xml
<code>
    <lol1>energy</lol1>
    <lol2>protein</lol2>
    <lol3>fat</lol3>
</code>
```

Is there any SimpleXML function to remove the document element?

Comment: Did you tried something or did some research?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete node with simplexml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148212/delete-node-with-simplexml)

Comment: @kittycat3141 DOM....i must't use this.(school project)

Comment: @user1477988 The first answer should work without DOM.

Comment: @kittycat3141 how can I do it without DOM? pls

Answer (score 1):

> I know there is some DOM library, however I don't want to use it

It is not technically possible in PHP SimpleXML to rename the document element, also known as root element (and often easily confused with the root node, which is the parent node of the document element and all it's siblings.)

And actually you can't rename it with DOMDocument either. But unlike in SimpleXML you can replace an element with [DOMDocument::replaceChild](http://php.net/DOMNode.replaceChild) easily.

With the given input:

```
$buffer = <<<XML
<nutrition>
    <code>
        <lol1>energy</lol1>
        <lol2>protein</lol2>
        <lol3>fat</lol3>
    </code>
</nutrition>
XML;
```

First create the **DOMDocument**:

```
$doc                     = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput       = true;
```

Then load your XML (for example as string `$buffer`) here:

```
$doc->loadXML($buffer);
```

Obtain the soon to become document element:

```
$code = $doc->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('*')->item(0);
```

Replace the document element and output to show it worked:

```
$doc->replaceChild($code, $doc->documentElement);
$doc->save('php://output');
```

This gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<code>
  <lol1>energy</lol1>
  <lol2>protein</lol2>
  <lol3>fat</lol3>
</code>
```

And that's it. Hope this is still helpful even if you normally prefer DOMDocument. But have no fear, it's a sister library of **SimpleXMLElement**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```php
$xmlstr = <<<'XML'
<nutrition>
    <code>
        <lol1>energy</lol1>
        <lol2>protein</lol2>
        <lol3>fat</lol3>
    </code>
</nutrition>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
foreach ($xml->xpath('/nutrition/child::code[1]') as $node) {
    $unwrappedXml = new \SimpleXMLElement($node->asXML());
    break;
}

echo $unwrappedXml->asXML();
```